# Electric charge of a triplet under $SU(2)_L$

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

Let us consider the Standard group $SU(3)_c \times SU(2)_L \times U(1)_Y$ and a particle $\chi$ transforming in the representation $(\bar{\textbf{3}},\textbf{3},1/3)$. After Electroweak symmetry breaking, the electric charge is defined as

$$
Q = Y+T^3_L
$$

where $Y,T^3_L$ are the generator of $U(1)_Y$ and the diagonal generator of $SU(2)_L$.

I am confused in identifying the $T^3_L$ charge of the components of $\chi$, that I need to understand if, after EWSB, the left-over particles are electrically charged.

How can I compute the various $U(1)_{em}$ representations resulting from EWSB?

Comment: How did you identify, or compute, the charges of W,Z, and γ? Before discussing hypothetical particles, have you satisfied yourself you fully understand the [extant ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge)?

Comment: For the gauge bosons this is my way.
$W_+^\mu$ is associated to $T^+ = 1/2(T^1 + i T^2)$ and then the commutator $[T^3_L,T^+] = T^3_L$ gives +1. Similarly for the others.

Comment: So you know the eigenvalues of $T^3$ for an "isospin"-1 object are (1,0,-1). Where is the trouble?

Comment: I don't think I can apply the same trick for another representation, say the representation $\textbf{5}$. I just took the easiest example, apparently too easy, since I can use SM case to answer.

Comment: Ok, So I can just use the $J_\pm$ generators of the $SU(2)$ on the $2j+1-th$ dimensional space to construct the eigenspace. The eigenstates have eigenvalue $j,j-1,...,-j$  So, for the $\textbf{5}$ we have $2,1,0,-1,-2$.

Comment: Correct. It's in the quantum angular momentum discussion of any introduction to QM. The formulas are the same---only the interpretation varies.

Comment: You read off [$S_z$ in here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins). Make sure your weak hypercharge is normalized in the conventions of your representation label.